# Edits must be at least six characters when reformatting

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

Often times the question asker forgot to indent the code by 4 spaces, so I edit the code to reformat it, but I get this message. This is the case even if I indent many lines (I guess it ignores white space characters?)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters

Answer (score 4):

## Improve more stuff in that post.  Indentation isn't everything.

By and large, there are other things that can be fixed in that question; very *rarely* have I seen a question that's just an indentation fix.

If it really *is* just that minor, then you might have to wait until you earn the privilege to edit everywhere.  Minor edits like that really shouldn't be put into a peer review queue; if there's more substantial changes, *please* do make them.

Since you can leave comments, a comment requesting indentation fix wouldn't be the worst thing to happen to that question/answer.  Usually, someone with full edit privileges can come in and edit the post's formatting pretty quickly.  Or, the OP can come along and indent it themselves if they really did forget to do that.

So no, this isn't a bug.  It's a quirk in the system; you should be looking to **improve more stuff** in that post.

Comment: What about cases where code edits need to be made that are less than six characters, but are syntactically important? I just tried to edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554502/menu-full-width-of-the-page/24554530#24554530) because he didn't fix the OP's broken closing `</ul>` tag, but was stopped by the six-character minimum.